# How do I assign a variable to refer to an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

- Disclaimer: I am pretty much a novice to Swift so prepare to cringe.

I have a series of arrays set out, when a user taps a button I would like one of these arrays to be called so I can use it in a function. They are named with thisArray then a number, i.e: thisArray1, thisArray2, etc.

I cannot find a way to make this work, the closest I have come to what I want is shown below but as you can all tell this definitely does not work.

`var currentArray = "thisArray" + selectedArrayNumber`

The outcome of this is to use the variable like below:

`button1.setTitle(currentArray[1], for .normal)`

If any of you can shed some light on this situation and tell me how badly I have gone wrong that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Duly cringed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of your arrays, and then retrieve it using the selectedArrayNumber.

```
let arrays = [thisArray1, thisArray2, etc]
let currentArray = arrays[selectedArrayNumber]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this isn't quite what I'm after I don't think. I want to be able to call an array by giving my function the integer, not "thisArray1".

Comment: Never mind, I am a fool. Thank you very much, the simplest ways are always the best.